# Does MacCready's Killshot perk only affect body parts labeled as 'head' in VATS?

Tags: fallout-4

Does MacCready's [Killshot](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Killshot) perk only affect body parts labeled as 'head' in VATS? What about those creatures or NPCs with no 'head' part in VATS?

For example: radscorpions (they have no 'head' part but have a 'face' part), the various different [turrets](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Automated_turret_%28Fallout_4%29), Mister Handy / Gutsy robots. Do they have body parts that are affected by the Killshot perk's 20% increased VATS accuracy?

Answer (score 3):

**MacReady's perk will affect anything called Head, and also some similar things.** This includes the 'face' part of a radscorpion, and even the 'barrel' part of a machine gun turret. My informal tests indicate that none of the Mr. Handy or its variants' limbs count, although you might think the eyes would. The vast majority of enemies have a limb explicitly labeled 'head'.

This is based on my own experience having the perk on two playthroughs, including my current one. This perk used to be bugged, giving a *2000%* percent boost. This was a potentially game-breaking bug that essentially set your head hit-percentage to 95%. This made it quite easy to see which body parts were affected. Based on playtime after it was patched, it's possible that turret barrels are no longer included, but it's harder to tell.

Comment: Thankfully (for those that want to play the game as was originally intended), it looks like Killshot will be fixed in the patch that is [currently beta on steam](http://www.destructoid.com/the-next-fallout-4-update-makes-settlements-slightly-better-334632.phtml): `MacReady's Killshot perk now calculates headshot percentages properly`. Pesky decimal points... always making my 20% into 2000%!

Comment: @king14nyr Looks like there's some good stuff in there. Particularly interested in "Added status menu for settlers in your settlements"

Comment: Yes, there's a lot of good stuff coming down the pipe, it's definitely worth a read. A lot of quest fixes too, for those that are running into glitches that prevent progress through it.

Comment: For PC players there's already multiple mods made to fix that problem

Comment: Know any other parts affected besides the radscorpion's face and the machine gun turret's barrel? Yep, I'm aware of the Killshot bug, and have installed the [Simple Bug Fixes](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/2142/?) mod to fix it.

Comment: @galacticninja Not off the top of my head, no. Most things have heads. The gun barrel one really stuck out to me over the weekend. I didn't even really think about 'face' not being 'head' until you mentioned it, but I know that works. I fought some radscorpions in the glowing sea last night.

Comment: I have mixed feelings on the bugged nature of this patch.  On the one hand, I've got ~150 hours in my play through and I kind of think I should feel like a superman at this point.  But on the other hand, it is a bit OP when I can take out an entire room of raiders with one visit to VATS.

Comment: @RESPAWN It makes mirelurks into jokes. I can shoot a mirelurk in the face when it is almost completely turned around and hunched over. It's also absurd outside. I can headshot guys on the ground with a pistol from a broken interstate hundreds of feet in the air.

Comment: @DCShannon I only got the perk this past weekend (I put MacCready off for a while) and haven't really had much time with it yet.  I'm not going to lie when I say that it has been fun so far, but I hear what you are saying.  The game should represent at least some challenge.